# What is the Japanese term for an old man/grandpa who is into anime/is otaku?

Tags: japanese-language, terminology

Is there a casual/slang term in Japanese for an old geezer who's a hardcore otaku? I know terms like erojiji and such but there are more referred to old men who are just perverted in general, but what about perverted old otaku?

Comment: Cross-posted to Japanese.SE: [Is おたくじじい a proper term to describe an old man who's into anime or is there another slang term for it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86191/5464)

Comment: Define old men. When does one becomes old? (sorry for being rhetoric). I can think of "[kimo-ota](https://www.wordsense.eu/kimoota/)" or kimochi-warui otaku which roughly translates to disgusting or filthy otaku. They are kind of dirty, unhygienic and unemployed people who are obsessive about anime. Although I don't know the correct term for "Perverted old otaku" in japanese but it may come under kimo-ota.

Answer (score 2):

Kitanai rōjin is what I have found about from your question.

It means dirty old man too if you want to translate.